# How to avoid htaccess rewrite rule from modifiying link on php

Tags: php, file, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Alright, so pretty much I have this on Htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*) index2.php?url=$1
```

And I'm trying to execute in a php file the following

```
mime_content_type('Doggy.png')
```

and it returns an error saying path of file not found, which I'm pretty sure it does exist,
trying to find what the error could be I ended thinking it's htaccess.

Can anybody help me solve this?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: To make sure if the problem is in rewrite rules or not - disable rewrite and see if you still have the problem. `mime_content_type` with path to file does not make any http requests, so rewrite rules should not be a problem *in that call*

Comment: You're right, problem isn't the rewrite rule.

Comment: However, the path for the image is correct. But still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not your .htaccess rules. Those only rewrite *HTTP requests* into file execution rules. Once your PHP executes, they have no influence anymore whatsoever.

The problem is simply that the file `Doggy.png` does not exist **relative to the file where this command is executed**. The file must be in the same directory as `index2.php`, assuming that's the file that contains the line `mime_content_type('Doggy.png')`. Otherwise you need to use relative paths like `mime_content_type('../Doggy.png')` or `mime_content_type('img/Doggy.png')`.

Comment: I'm sure they're in the same location: 
http://prntscr.com/bi6bf
http://prntscr.com/bi6cl

Thank you for replying.

Answer (score 0):

As we've established already, the problem is not in rewrite rules.

What actually matters is not he relative location of the **files**, but rather location of your image file relative to a **working directory**.

For example, if your directory structure is:

```
/
/index.php
/inc/imagelib.php
/inc/Doggy.png
```

and you're doing manipulation on Doggy from the `imagelib.php`, but it is actually *included* from `index.php` and your working directory is `/`, then, *despite being in the same folder*, you'll need to address the file as `inc/Doggy.png`.

The **working directory** may change, depending on what your entry point in the program will be (in case of a web application - where was the file that originally got the request), or (in case of command line), where were you in shell when executing the command.

To avoid problems with relative paths, i suggest using absolute paths.

So (assuming the same scenario as in the previous example), in `imagelib.php` you would need to construct the path to image path like this:

```
`$absolute_path = dirname(__FILE__)."/Doggy.png"`
```